# Using ISL9241 Buck-Boost Battery Charger for an AMD Motherboard (Without an EC)

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, embedded, hardware

I want to use [ISL9241](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/098Mj4EpuPOYr6iiMmGXd177w#ISL9241) Buck-Boost Battery Charger for a system that has [AMD Ryzen™ 9 PRO 6950HS](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-9-pro-6950hs) APU.
I saw that also in AMD reference design and Intel Tiger Lake UP3 reference design, ISL9241 was used with the combination of EC (Embedded Controller)

Our design doesn't include EC and we want to look for a solution (with active monitoring with the APU) that doesn't require us to add an EC.

Is there an IC solution that can be placed between the ISL9241 and the APU and could replace EC? or any other workaround which can still enable active monitoring from the APU?

Comment: Why not just get a small uC and be done with it? It will make your life a lot easier and won't add much to the cost.

Comment: @JohnD, do you know any uC that are compatible with ISL9241 and AMD APU?